# How to work out MultipleChoice filters on Listview using checkbox

Tags: android, filter, multiple-choice

I have different categories of filters like id, name, gender, area, caste, religion. Now i want to use multiple choice filters showing checkboxes, how can i work out with multiple choice filters because there are many kind of filters so permutation & combination  is worst for it.
currently i am done with single selection of filter (1 checkbox true at a time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str[] = new String[('Z' - 'A') + 1];
boolean selectedItems[] = new boolean[str.length];
protected ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedChars = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
private AlertDialog alertBox;

private void showSpinner() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    int a = 0;
    for (char c = 'A'; c < 'Z'; c++) {
        str[a++] = String.valueOf(c);
    }
    boolean[] checkedChars = new boolean[str.length];
    int count = str.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        checkedChars[i] = selectedChars.contains(str[i]);

    alertBuilder.setTitle("Select Country");
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    alertBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(str, selectedItems,
            new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked)
                        selectedChars.add(str[which]);
                    else
                        selectedChars.remove(str[which]);
                }
            });

    alertBox = alertBuilder.create();
    alertBox.show();
}
```

it will jst display the spinner with mulitple selection options.

Comment: see i am done with multi-choice filter, but problem is ,there are many kind of filters , eg : user may select 2-3 or  may be all at a time, i have to check each and every condition for multiselection manually.

Comment: for single selection i am done as like 1 checkbox true other all false and then query for that method.